# How to import SSH private key?

Tags: linux, ssh, key, rsa, private

I'm pretty new to SSH authentication. A friend has allowed me access to his server and has sent me a private key in the form of:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: blah blah blah
long encryption string
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

My (basic) question is, how do I import this on my client machine to give me access to his server? I initially thought I'd just add an entry to authorized_keys on my machine but what's already there is in a different format to what my friend's sent. Do I need to convert something here? I've been reading around lots and am beginning to wonder if he's not done this the wrong way around - should I generate the key pair on my machine & send him my private key? Sorry, new to this as stated.

Server and client are both Linux.

Comment: SSL or SSH? You mention SSL but authorized_keys is a file related to SSH.

Comment: Sorry, I meant SSH, doh!

Comment: Don't forget that you can [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mean SSH :)

Normally, you generate a key on your local machine using [ssh-keygen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) and send your *public* key (.ssh/id_rsa.pub) to be added to the file .ssh/authorized_keys in your home directory on the server.

That should let you log in without a password on the server, and no one but you (including the server owner) has your private key, so it can be reused for login on other servers too.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me! I guess I was right in thinking that my friend was approaching this the wrong way around, but it's the public key that I send over.

Big thanks!

Comment: Sometimes admins generate the private portions of keys if they don't want to bother users with the details of how to generate them -- or worse, _share their keys amongst each other_.

Answer (score 0):

If you use putty, please add your private key in below dialog [image: connection->ssh->auth]

Comment: "Server and client are both Linux."